# Open File in targeted Visual Studio Thread

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I have a custom piece of functionality in a Visual Studio that allows me to right click an opened file and automatically open related files. This is driven by a Powershell script, similar to the article outlined below.

https://nickmeldrum.com/blog/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010

```
param(
[string]$path
)

[string]$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($path)
[string]$newPath

if ($extension = ".js")
{
    $newPath = $path -replace ".js", ".tmpl.html"
    $newPath = $newPath -replace "\\modules\\", "\templates\"
}else{
    $newPath = $path -replace ".tmpl.html", ".js"
    $newPath = $newPath -replace "\\templates\\", "\modules\"
}

Write-Host "Opening:"$newPath
Invoke-Item -path $newPath
```

The Powershell script uses *Invoke-Item -Path* to open the document(s). The jenky part, was having to associate *.js and *.html files with Visual Studio but it works.

The problem I'm facing... I have a FrontEnd project and a Backend project open simultaneously, the *Invoke-Item -Path* call opens the associated documents in whatever project it wants (I'm not sure if it's the first or last project opened). I know this probably relates to the file association described earlier. Is there a better way to handle this, whether ditch powershell, target a process id, etc?

Open to ideas/thoughts

Comment: `if ($extension = ".js")` should be `if ($extension -eq ".js")` Now, you're **assigning** '.js' to the $extension variable. This means your code will never enter the `else` part.

Comment: Thanks for that! Still in the process of rewriting. The problem stands, is there a way to target the Visual Studio thread invoking the open action?